# ofstream и указатель на строку

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется файловый поток вывода ofstream.

И есть кусок проблемного кода:

```
int Write(TCHAR* message)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(_T("test.txt"), ios_base::app);
    file << message << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Вызываю функцию следующим образом Write(_T("test")); но в файле получаю адрес памяти (0041FE94). Вопрос вот в чем: объясните новичку, как вывести саму строку, а не адрес по которому она находится в памяти?

Comment: у вас вероятно в опциях проекта установлено `Use Unicode Character Set`, поэтому для корректной работы используйте wofstream, либо вызывайте как `Write("test");`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно!